# Elasticsearch create multi index on a daily bases

Tags: elasticsearch

I load this index in elasticsearch

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/filebeat?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "template1": {
            "mapping": {
              "doc_values": true,
              "ignore_above": 50000,
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "{dynamic_type}"
            },
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "offset": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": "true"
        },
        "geoip"  : {
          "type" : "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "2s"
  },
  "template": "filebeat-*"
}
'
```

and the result of `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'` is filebeat-2018-02-05
and every day on index add to the list of elasticsearch on a daily basies and I have to add it in kibana if I want to search on my latest log file. why elasticsearch add multiple index on a daily bases. and how can I solve this problem (just have my own indexes)
thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're pushing data to elasticsearch using filebeat.

1. Elasticsearch doesnt decide what index your data should be written to. It is filebeat that tells elasticsearch where the data should be written. And the default behaviour of filebeat/logstash is to create a new new index every day.
2. If you want to visualize data for a range of index patterns, you can use the wildcard symbol in your kibana index pattern, say filebeat-*. And all visualizations created against filebeat-* should have aggregated data from all your filebeat- indices.
3. The reason to have a new index everyday is to help with the logging use case, where new data is more valuable than old data. Hence, this gives an opportunity to easily retire old data, or to move old indices to a less performant elasticsearch node etc.
4. If you still need a new pattern, you should be able to modify your filebeat config file and specify the new index_pattern value. [Document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#index-option-es)